# Python -passing imgdata pointer to a function in C using ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, pixel, ctypes

I've been trying to get an imgdata string of hexadecimal (unicode latin-1) values passed from Python via a pointer to imgdata to a function in C that I wrote.  The C function will convert these hexadecimal source values which are Blue Green Red and Alpha to greyscale and then return the converted imgdata to the dst pointer address.

Currently the source values that C function prints out are not correct and much different than the hexadecimal values in imgdata. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong when passing imgdata in Python to my C function?  Is my ctypes datatype wrong?

Output from c function:
src values: 120 src values: 212 src values: 201 src values: 1 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0 src values: 0

Values should be:
4,8,20,0,1,7,12,0,6,7,14,0

Python code:

```
#imgdata format is BGRA
imgdata = '\x04\x08\x14\x00\x01\x07\x0c\x00\x06\x07\x0e\x00'
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('path/to/my/lib/testlib.so')
source = (c_char_p * 12) (imgdata) 
destination = (c_uint8 * 12)()
testlib.grey.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.c_int)
src = pointer(source)
dst = pointer(destination)
testlib.grey(dst,src,3)
p = ctypes.string_at(dst,12)
byte_array = map(ord, p)
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void grey(uint8_t *dst, uint8_t *sc, int num_pixels) {
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<12; k++)
    {
      printf("src values: %d ", *sc++);
    }
    // additional BGRA to Greyscale conversion code not shown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python isn't that hard you want it to be. This would look sort of:

```
    imgdata = '\x04\x08\x14\x00\x01\x07\x0c\x00\x06\x07\x0e\x00'
    testlib = ctypes.CDLL('path/to/my/lib/testlib.so')
    dest = (c_uint8 * 12)()
    testlib.grey(dest, imgdata, 12)
    byte_array = bytearray(dest) # if you really neeed it
```

**Edit**: read voted up [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s comments (irrelevant since he deleted them). He explains how to make it right with your approach.

Oh, well, he insisted, so here's his code:

```
    imgdata = '\x04\x08\x14\x00\x01\x07\x0c\x00\x06\x07\x0e\x00'
    testlib = ctypes.CDLL('path/to/my/lib/testlib.so')
    dest = (ctypes.c_char * len(imgdata))()
    testlib.grey.restype = None
    testlib.grey.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
    testlib.grey(dest, imgdata, len(dest))
    byte_array = bytearray(dest) # or just use dest.raw which is a python str
```

and his explanation:

`c_char_p` is a `char*` and an array of 12 char pointers is incorrect, and passing a pointer to that is doubly incorrect, and the only reason it didn't die in a `ArgumentError` is that `c_void_p` in `argtypes` accepts a lot without complaining -- Python integers and strings, and ctypes pointers and arrays.

Comment: @eryksun I appreciate your comment and I really understand that your approach is right. But it doesn't help him as you can see. He creates an array of 12 char pointers, and then he takes pointer to what is already pointers, and after all finishes it with void* prototyped function arguments. So I just tried to make this code small and clear

Comment: @eryksun I agree with your approach. It's vital for big projects development. My point is that there was too many mistakes in OP's code while he was trying to follow it that it would be better to write the code as easy as he can. So, only in this concrete situation I prefer 1st answer's version.

Comment: thanks @qwm for the corrections and comments on the several things I had wrong.  I've tested your code above and works perfectly!

Comment: @bfalz oh, that's good 'cause I can't say i've tested it. You're welcome.